# What type of problem is finding the number of "alterations" on a vector whose components take values from a known set?

Tags: permutations, vectors

What type of problem is finding the number of "alterations" on a vector whose components take values from a known set?

E.g.

$(x_0,x_1,x_2)$

$x_i \in \{0,1 \}$

Find all possible three-vectors.

Particularly, how should one "deal" with such vector problems? Should one e.g. list them as $x_0 x_1 x_2$ or something else, dismissing the indices?

Comment: They are the edges of a cube.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe But what does that imply about studying $k$-length binary permutations?

Comment: If I read correctly, the number of permutations of $k$ elements is $2^k$. But here comes a confusion: if the set of values that are being taken is larger than the number of positions?

Comment: @mavavilj: If you have a set $x$ with $n$ unique values, there are $n^k$ possible $k$-vectors (with components from $x$). It does not matter if $n \gt k$ or $n \le k$ or $n = k$, as long as $1 \le n, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.